# Sites offering open-source sound tracks/music for use in applications?

Tags: creative-commons, media

Are there any good sites offering open-source tracks for use in applications or games? I've seen many, but seem to be any good... giving links to last.fm and other sites.

Comment: Questions asking for a external product are off-topic since they do not involve a specific open source issue themselves. I'm not sure where you can ask for music though... Have you tried searching [search.creativecommons.org](http://search.creativecommons.org)?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'll check that out... btw I've asked this on three stackexchange sites - all of them closed the question :(

Comment: Yeah, recommendations aren't necessarily the greatest fit for SE, and we only have sites for software and hardware recs. Sorry about that :/ I hope that site works good for you, it offers searches for items that are licensed under creative commons.

Comment: The Creative Commons website would be a good place to start.

Comment: @DevRobot Sorry about that. As Zizouz212 says, recommendations aren't the best fit for many Stack Exchange sites - though there is a [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations) proposal for a site which you might be interested in following.

Comment: @ArtOfCode thnx I will check that out - atm I've found bensound.com very useful - from a recommendation by an askubuntu user